# Switch storyboard according to orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

Currently I have set up my storyboard that is optimised for landscape mode. At first I figured I would only allow landscape orientation. However along the way I decided it would be better to allow both options. What I've done now is created a new storyboard that holds the layout for the portrait orientation.

I did it this way because the views will be completely set up differently. Is there a way to switch between storyboards during runtime based on orientation or is what I'm doing really bad practice and would it be advised to go a different direction.

I figured using xib files would cause duplicated code, I might be completely wrong so. I would love to know if it's possible to switch storyboards based on orientation and if so how to achieve this. And if this would be good practice at all. The way I've set it up now the storyboards both use the same view controllers so they all use the same methods/outlets

***Edit based on Haroldo Gondim's awnser***

I put this in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the AppDelegate.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

then I have this function in the app delegate class as well

```
func rotated(){
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "portrait", bundle: nil)
    }
    //self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController()
    storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController")
    //self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

I also tried this with `instantiateInitialViewController`

but whatever I try it won't change the storyboard. It does go into the if statement the way it should

Answer (score 2):

Xcode storyboard has a great feature for this called size classes. At first its a bit hard to get your head around but hopefully the tutorial will help

http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Answer (score 2):

The built-in size classes allows you to build completely different UI on the same storyboard. The runtime will select the appropriate scene / controls for the current device/orientation (size class) and will layout automatically (leveraging AutoLayout). Review the size classes feature in your local Xcode help as it is quite easy to use. Essentially, Layout entire scene in all sizes and then change size class (to reference new orientation) before laying out new scene (with all new UI if you like)...

Link up the new UI and you're done.

*Q: Wouldn't you get a lot of code copy?*

### Response

> If you are rearranging UI elements using size classes, then you do
>   **not** use multiple VCs. If you are creating new UI elements then you would need to add IBOutlets and view manipulation code like any new
>   control one would normally add to an existing ViewController. Using
>   auto layout and size classes one can rearrange existing views without
>   any code adjustments at all. The layout changes are hidden inside of
>   the Storyboard file as xml. If you right-click on a storyboard file
>   you can open as source code and see that. To revert right-click and
>   open as interface builder.

Comment: Wouldn't you get a lot of code copy? With this I mean wouldn't you be using the same code multiple times because every size class has it's own views/viewcontroller. This is just something I'm wondering. I know about the size class option. I've never actually used it before, I stayed away from it because I was afraid I would have to redo everything (which is basically true since I've created the views with the any setting)

Comment: size classes are quite the opposite - think about it is as super classes for interface builder the any-any size class is an abstract layout that does not correspond to any actual iphone or ipad screen - but what you build in this size class can be displayed on any screen as the constraints you build are all relative. It is always recommended to this size class first - when you then want to do specific layouts for different orientations you would use the compact height size class which is generic for all iphones in landscape - you then simply change the elements youd like to change

Comment: @Blakusl I did end up trying to use the size classes not much of a problem so far. however I want the view for the iPad landscape and portrait to be different as well. But they both seem to be using the Regular height and width size class. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

`Autolayout` can allow you to rearrange the view for different orientation.

For different functionalitys and elements, you should use `Size Class`, Follow the tutorial @Blakusl linked, is very good.

Answer (score 0):

Check the device orientation and instantiate your storyboard according to orientation.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard;

if(([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
{
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardLandscape" bundle: nil];    
} else {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardPortrait" bundle: nil];
}

[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerIdentifier"];
```

#### Edit

In each view controller you have to add an identifier

[image: Identifier]

Comment: Where would you do this? inside the app delegate?
Also I'm using swift, not that it matters much I have no problem rewriting it just wondering where I would put this exactly

Comment: You should use in: 1) App Delegate when starts your app. 2) When you calling to change the screen. 3) When you change orientation (I am not sure in this but I think in viewWillAppear)

Comment: I did it in a different way which just uses the app delegate class. However just one question what is the `viewControllerIdentifier` in this case? Just the name of my view controller that is used for the initial view controller?

Comment: In each view controller you have to add an identifier. I added a image in the question.

Comment: I think in the first execution you must executed the code in rotated func.
and after you register the NSNotificationCenter (just for future change orientation).

Comment: it doesn't add the storyboard at all tho. even when I change orientation while it's running it just doesn't change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105359/discussion-between-nosixties-and-haroldo-gondim).